# How to show homomorphism of groups

Tags: group-theory

How can I show that $G=\{ 1, g \} \cong  (\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ ?

Do I have to find a function $f:G \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that:

$$f(a \cdot b)=f(a)+f(b)$$

where $a,b \in G$?

If so, how can I find such a function?

Comment: there is a theorem that states that every prime order group is cyclic. I suppose you can't use this though?

Comment: Is $G$ already a group? If so, what is the binary operation?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, $G$ is a group. The binary operation is the multiplication.

Comment: @Jeremy How can I use this theorem?

Comment: @evinda: What does multiplication mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is closed under the operation.  Assuming $1$ is your identity element, then note that this means $g^2 = 1$, else we'd have $g^2 = g \implies g = 1$.

Use this information to explicitly define your homomorphism.

Comment: I understand.. But, how can I use this, to find a homomorphism?

Comment: @evinda, when I say that you can explicitly define a homomorphism, what I mean is that, for each individual element in the group, you can select an element in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to send it to and then check that your map satisfies $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$.

Comment: Can we do it like that, because we have $2$ elements? What would we do, if we would have a lot of elements?

Comment: @evinda, it would be much harder with lots of elements, but it's trivial in this case.  There are certain results that make this unnecessary for larger groups.  For example, the fact that all groups of prime order are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ under addition.

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The function is
$f(1)=0,f(g)=1$

Comment: So, do I not have to find a specific function?

Comment: That is a specific function.